# Start WildFly server in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

I read many answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667380/how-configure-eclipse-kepler-to-use-wildfly). But in start server window (Jboss Community item) I can chose only JBoss Runtime server. There is no WildFly server item. 
[image]

How can I add it?

I installed JBoss Tools 4.0.1.Final version cause I use Eclipse Juno. Should I install JBoss Tools 4.2.0.Final even without Eclipse Luna 4.4?

Comment: Did you install the JBoss Tools -> JBoss AS module?

Comment: @peeskillet i installed it not from market place, i did it from direct link via help->install new software from here http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/juno/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WildFly support in JBoss Tools 4.2.x is for Eclipse Luna only. So, it's not possible to use on Eclipse Kepler.